# Form post to controller#action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my `adminpage#index` controller i have defined `@software`:

```
if Software.first != nil
      @software = Software.first
        else
      @software = Software.new
end
```

Then in my form i have:

```
  <% form_for(@software), :url => adminpage_setting_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.label 'Name der zugelassenen Software' %>
  <%= f.text_field :software %><br>
  <%= f.label 'Software-Relase' %>
  <%= f.text_field :release %><br>
  <%= f.label 'Softwareverantwortlicher' %>
  <%= f.text_field :sv %><br>
  <% end %>
```

Somehow this invokes an error:

```
  syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
 ';  form_for(@software), :url => adminpage_setting_pa...
                         ^
```

I really have no clue what i made wrong! Thanks

Comment: Not part of your question, but a cleaner way to do your adminpage#index would be: `@software = Software.first_or_initialze`...  Nil checks usually indicate something could be improved in the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `:url => adminpage_setting_path` is actually the second parameter to the `form_for` method.

It should be `form_for(@software, :url => adminpage_setting_path) do |f|`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
<% form_for(@software), :url => adminpage_setting_path do |f| %>
```

With:

```
<%= form_for @software, :url => adminpage_setting_path do |f| %>
```

EDIT:

Mini explanation as per requested by: [Helios de Guerra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19276265/form-post-to-controlleraction/19276354#comment28540589_19276354)

1. :url is a parameter of form_for as [sevenseacat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19276426/1251349) mentioned
2. I'm assuming you want the  < form > element tag to be printed. Therefore you should use <%= %> vs. just <% %>